# Do we have to show these two directions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We have that $A,B,C$ are subgroups of $G$ such that $A<C$.

I want to show that $AB\cap C=A(B\cap C)$.

$$$$

We have the following $$AB=\{ab\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$$ 
$$AB\cap C=\{x\mid x\in AB \text{ and } x\in C\}$$ 
$$B\cap C=\{y\mid y\in B \text{ and } y\in C\}$$ 
$$A(B\cap C)=\{az\mid a\in A,z\in B\cap C\}$$

right?

Do we have to show that $$x\in AB\cap C\Rightarrow x\in A(B\cap C)$$ and the reverse direction?

$$$$ 
Suppose that $x\in AB\cap C$, then $x=ab$ and $x\in C$. Since $A<C$, we have that $a\in C$, so $x\in CB$ and $x\in C$, right? Does this help to get the desired result?

Answer (score 2):

Show first $A(B\cap C)\subseteq AB\cap C$.

Since $A\subseteq C$ we have $A(B\cap C)\subseteq C(B\cap C)\subseteq CC\subseteq C$ and because of $B\cap C\subseteq B$ we have $A(B\cap C)\subseteq AB$. So together we get $A(B\cap C)\subseteq AB\cap C$.

Show now $A(B\cap C)\supseteq AB\cap C$.

Let be $x\in AB\cap C$. So $x\in C$ and there is $a\in A\subseteq C, b\in B$ with $x=ab$. It's enough to show that $b\in C$. But this is clear from $b=a^{-1}x\in AC\subseteq C$.

Comment: Why does it stand that $$C(B\cap C)\subseteq CC$$ ?

Comment: $B\cup C\subseteq C$ so  $C(B\cup C)\subseteq CC$. But if this step doesn't help you and it's clearer for you without it, then just leave it...

Comment: Ah ok... Which is the difference between $\subseteq $, $\leq $ and $ <$ ? Are $\subseteq$ and $\leq $ equivalent in this case?

Comment: $\subseteq$ means subset. I don't know what you mean by $\leq, <$, sometimes this means "subgroup" or "proper subgroup". A subgroup is a subset but not the other way around.

Comment: So, we use everywhere $\subseteq$ right?

Comment: It depends what you want to say. For example for saying $A$ is a proper subgroup in the preliminaries you should write $A< G$.

Comment: To show that $AB\cap C=A(B\cap C)$, do we have to show that $$AB\cap C\subseteq A(B\cap C) \text{ and } AB\cap C \supseteq A(B\cap C)$$ or $$AB\cap C\leq  A(B\cap C) \text{ and } AB\cap C \geq A(B\cap C)$$ ?

Comment: The first one. In general products of subgroups aren't groups

Comment: Why are products of subgroups in general not groups?

Comment: For example $\langle (1 2) \rangle \cdot \langle (1 3) \rangle = \{ (), (12), (13), (1 2 3) \}$ is not a subgroup of $S_n$, you need the two groups to permutate if you want their product to form a group.

Answer (score 2):

If $x\in C$ and $x=ab$ with $a\in A\subseteq C$ and $b\in B$ then $$b=a^{-1}x\in C$$ So $b\in B\cap C$ and $x=ab\in A(B\cap C)$, as was to be shown.

Converse:

If $x=az$ with $a\in A\subseteq C$ and $z\in B\cap C$ then $x\in AB$ (since $a\in A$ and $z\in B$) and $x\in C$ (since $a\in C$ and $z\in C$). So $x\in AB\cap C$

Comment: Doors it stand in general that $M\cap N\subseteq M$ and $M\cap N\subseteq N$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar $M\cap N \subseteq N, M$ holds for arbitrary sets and is pretty obvious from the definitions.

Comment: I See... Thanks!! @Stefan

Comment: We have that $a^{-1}\in A\subset C$ because $A$ and $C$ are subgroups, right? Why does it stand that $b\in B\cap C$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, subgroups are closed under taking inverses, and as they are also closed under composition you get $b \in B \cap C$.

Answer (score 2):

This is called *Dedekinds identity* in group theory. You almost got it in your computation. In addition to the other proofs, for the direction $AB \cap C \subseteq A(B\cap C)$ you can also note that every coset $Ab \subseteq C$ contains some $c \in Ab \subseteq Cb$, hence $C = Cb$ which gives $b \in C$. So that $b \in B\cap C$ and hence $Ab \subseteq A(B\cap C)$. The other inclusion is pretty obvious and just involves set theory (and so holds in more general algebraic structures as well), $A(B\cap C) \subseteq AB$ as $B\cap C \subseteq B$ and $A(B\cap C) \subseteq C(B\cap C) = C$ as $A \le C$ and $B \cap C \le C$.

Comment: At the last line you say $$C(B\cap C)=C$$ why does this stand? We have that $$C(B\cap C)\leq CC$$ right? Is $CC$ equal to $C$ ? And why do you use equality and not inequality?

Comment: Ah OK... Which is the difference between $\subseteq$ , $\leq $ and $<$ ?

Comment: $A \le B$ means $A$ is a subgroup of $B$, and $A \subseteq B$ merely means $A$ is a subset of $B$; but in the given context here we speak always about subgroups, so you could interchange $\subseteq$ and $\le$ in the answers. $<$ mean proper subgroup.

Comment: So, do we use everywhere $\leq$ above? Does it stand that $A\cap B\leq A$ and $A\cap B\leq B$ ? Or only with $\subseteq$ ?

Comment: What do you think? If $A$ and $B$ are subgroups, does this hold for $A \cap B$?

Comment: Yes, $A\cap B$ is also a subgroup, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: And when we have that $A\leq B$ and $A\geq B$, that implies that $A=B$, like when we have subsets, right?

Comment: If we define $A \le B$ to mean $A \subseteq B$ and $A$ is a group by itself then this is obvious.

Comment: I got stuck... sigmabe says in his last comment of his answer that in general products of subgroups aren't groups, why does this stand?

Comment: Is it well-known that $AB$ is a subgroup iff $AB = BA$. But I see now that I wrongly wrote $\le$ where $\subseteq$ should stand, of course something like $A(B\cap C) \le AB$ does not make sense in general if the sets do not form groups. Sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: Btw note that $A \le C$ and $B\cap C \le C$ is valid as these sets form subgroups.